# Unknown column 'priority' in 'field list' (INSERT INTO `store_categories`.....)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am getting this error when trying to load a .json file into my webpanel/webserver database:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'priority' in 'field list'
>
> INSERT INTO `store_categories` (`display_name`, `priority`,
>   `description`, `require_plugin`, `web_description`, `web_color`)
>   VALUES ('Hats', 0, 'Cosmetic hats that appear on your head.',
>   'equipment', NULL, '476291')
>
> Filename:
>   /usr/www/dynamic/public/server/store-webpanel-1.2.10-hf1/models/categories_model.php
>
> Line Number: 82

Here is the code:

```
        function get_category($id_category)
    {
        $DB_Main = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
        $DB_Main->where("id", $id_category);
        $query_category = $DB_Main->get('store_categories');
        if ($query_category->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return $query_category->row_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return array();
        }
    }

    function update_category($post)
    {
        $DB_Main = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
        $data = array(
            'display_name' => $post['display_name'],
            'description' => $post['description'],
            'require_plugin' => $post['require_plugin'],
            'web_description' => $post['web_description'],
            'web_color' => $post['web_color'],
            'priority' => $post['priority']
        );
        $DB_Main->where('id', $post['id']);
        $DB_Main->update('store_categories', $data);
    }

    function add_category($display_name, $description, $require_plugin, $web_description, $web_color, $priority=0)
    {
        $DB_Main = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
        $data = array(
            'display_name' => $display_name,
            'priority' => $priority,
            'description' => $description,
            'require_plugin' => $require_plugin,
            'web_description' => $web_description,
            'web_color' => $web_color
        );
        $DB_Main->insert('store_categories', $data);
        return $DB_Main->insert_id();
    }

    function remove_category($category_id)
    {
        $DB_Main = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
        $DB_Main->where('id', $category_id);
        $DB_Main->delete('store_categories');
    }

}
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Data type of 'priority ' is VARCHAR or TEXT ?

Comment: add a priority field to the store_categories table or change your code to reflect a field that exists on that table

Comment: I am sorry this isn't my code and I don't know source code, I am new to this so if anyone can post a fix of the problem please I would really appreciate it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is still relevant to Jack (the original author) almost 2 years later, but if anyone else stumbles across this quite rare web topic as it relates to the TF2 and CSGO Store and the MySQL Web Panel that is used to help administer the in-game Store, the following worked for me and will hopefully help you as well.

I actually just added the priority column into 2 tables as follows:

1. Using MySQL Workbench open a new SQL script window
2. Double-click the "store" schema on the left to associate the schema with your SQL script.
3. Execute the following 2 SQL commands:

   ```
   alter table store_items add column priority int(11) null;

   alter table store_categories add column priority int(11) null;
   ```